# Adding SKNodes to SKScene slowing animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a `SKScene`, in which I have a timer callback (not run loop) that at each time step updates the scene by adding and/or removing SKNodes. The idea is to animate the nodes travelling down in a straight line. Below is the code in my callback.

```
    // 1. Add new nodes

    let newSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "file")

    newSprite.position = (pos, pos)
    spriteList.append((sprite: newSprite, position: 0))
    scene.addChild(newSprite)

    var removeList = [Int]()

    let action = SKAction.move(to: (new, pos), duration: 5.0)
    newSprite.run(action)

    // 2. Update node positions
    for (i,_) in spriteList.enumerated() {
        spriteList[i].position += 1
        if spriteList[i].position > gridLength {
            removeList.append(i)
        }
    }

    // 3. Remove old nodes
    for i in removeList {
        spriteList[i].sprite.removeFromParent()
        spriteList.remove(at: i)
    }
```

At the moment, each time this callback runs, the animation stutters. When the callback stops and I have no more nodes to add, the rest of the nodes in the scene animate smoothly down. Any suggestions how I can fix this? Is the problem adding the nodes, running the logic, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a SKScene, in which I have a timer callback (not run loop)

### Don't do it

You should never use timers with SpriteKit, always stick to the run loop instead.

### Actions

If you want to repeat a block of code every `n` seconds just use actions

```
class Scene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)

        let action = SKAction.run { [unowned self] in
            // <--- put the codwe you want to repeat every 2 seconds here
        }

        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action, wait])
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
        run(repeatForever)
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, this makes sense, however still every time the action runs the code the same stuttering happens.

Comment: currently just 10, maybe my loop just takes too long? each loop i create a new node, add it to the scene, and loop over the other ones.

Comment: 10 nodes should not be a problem by a performance point of view

Comment: still struggling, it says its running at 42 fps but every time the timer comes around the animations of the other nodes already actioned stops briefly, the fps doesn't drop

Comment: Are you still using a timer?

Comment: just got it to work using your way, but the problem was apparently creating the nodes, scaling, adding to parent, etc each update step. to fix i generated all nodes at beginning and then ran the action/wait like you suggested